# Exception safety in C++ code

Tags: c++, exception

```
struct CImpl {
    A a;
    B b;
};

class C {
    unique_ptr<CImpl> pImpl;
    ...
    void f() {
        auto temp = make_unique<CImpl> (*pImpl);
        temp->a.method1();
        temp->b.method2();
        std::swap(pImpl, temp); // no throw
    }
};
```

Consider this example above; we are dealing with exceptions

(1)Now consider that `a.method1(), b.method2()` are both no-throw.

In this case does `f` offer a no-throw guarantee? I think *yes.*

(2)Now consider that `a.method1(), b.method2()` are both strong guarantee (if exception thrown, its as if nothing happened). Then in this case, we can guarantee `f` is strong because we are using temporaries so if exception occurs, `C` remains untouched.

Is this right? All this also follows because `std::swap(**, **)` is no-throw.

Comment: What if `~A()` or `~B()` throws an exception?

Comment: @Bathsheba, its a general consensus, that throwing an exception in dtors is a bad choice, so we roll with that assumption

Comment: Waht about `std::bad_alloc`? I don't think you need to look past the first line of `f`.

Comment: @Bana: You ought to put that into the question to keep pedants like me away.

Comment: Concerning part (2): Strong guarantee would require `method1()` to be side-effect free. If that call has a side effect, then that won't be undone when the call to `method2()` throws.

Answer (score 3):

There's no guarantee that this line won't throw an exception:

```
auto temp = make_unique<CImpl> (*pImpl);
```

All of the involved copy constructors there could throw.
So no `f()` isn't strongly exception safe.

Comment: I am not sure and please excuse my layman wording, but doesnt "strong exception guarantee" just mean that in case of an excetion everything is cleaned up nicely and whoever catches the excetion can continue without problems? To my understanding `f` may throw, but still can make the strong exception guarantee, because if the first line throws nothing bad happended. Please correct me if I am talking nonsense ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Looks like I overlooked what the OP's actually after: _"... `C` remains untouched ..."_. If that's the meaning of _strong guarantee_ then OP's code is fine as is.

Comment: OP was asking whether `f` is `nothrow` and I agree that it is not. I am just not sure about the exception guarantee which is something different afaik